# PHP - reach open_basedir maximum security

Tags: php, security, server, open-basedir, ispconfig

I run a server for several websites, driven by ISPConfig. There are (for now) 4 php versions installed : `5.6`, `7.0`, `7.2`, `7.3`.
I would like to maximize the security and I arrived at the `open_basedir` settings. The directories allowed are :

```
[website_path]/web
[website_path]/private
[website_path]/tmp
/var/www/[website_domain]/web
/srv/www/[website_domain]/web
/usr/share/php5
/usr/share/php
/tmp
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
/etc/phpmyadmin
/var/lib/phpmyadmin
/dev/random
/dev/urandom
```

I'd like to remove as much dirs as possible. Do you have any recommendations about that ?

Comment: Consider posting this kind of questions to the appropriate stack exchange website.

Comment: It would be a pleasure, but which one would it be ? Isn't it a PHP question ?